# Get classes that have fields annotated with Redstone's @Field()

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors, redstone.dart

I have some Dart classes in my project where I annotate some fields with [Redstone Mapper](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/redstone_mapper)'s `@Field()` annotation.

How can I get all these classes at runtime?

I've seen the private Map `_cache` in `redstone_mapper_factory`... but it's *private*.

I'm aware of that I can use the `Reflection` package to scan these classes myself, however all of them are already being detected and stored by the Redstone mapper so I'd like to leverage that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dart:mirror` to do that.

But I don't think it's possible to get that by redstone, you should probably ask on github, even do the change yourself if you want and do a pull request, it should not be difficult, it is just a getter on `_cache`.

https://github.com/redstone-dart/redstone_mapper

Comment: I think `_cache` contains mappings for other types, such as int, String, etc... So I might need to do some filtering.